# Deserializing Yaml file into custom classes is not working

Tags: c#, class, serialization, yaml

Hey i am trying do deserialize my yaml file into custom classes, check if the required properties are there an if there is a path given to a tag check if this path exists(path checker not done yet)

For checking things and work with the file i thought it is easy when i have a list containing other list and so one.

```
gc:
  - clean:
      - location: blah blah
        pattern: blah
      - location: blah blah
        pattern: blah
    dependencies:
      location: blah
  - solution:
      results: blah
      framework: blah
    test:
      configuration: blah
      results: blah blah
```

This could be my yaml file but the structure is not every time the same. In the end i need a list "gc" that contains **four** lists "clean, dependencies, solution, test".

```
public class CalcYamlFile
{
    [YamlMember(Alias = "gc", ApplyNamingConventions = false)]
    public List<CalcTag> GcTag { get; set; }
}
public class CalcTag
{
    public List<Clean> Clean { get; set; }
    public List<Dependencies> Dependencies { get; set; }
    public List<Solution> Solution { get; set; }
    public List<Test> Test { get; set; }
}
public class Clean
{
    [Required]
    public object Location { get; set; }
    public object Pattern { get; set; }
}
public class Dependencies
{
    [Required]
    public object Location { get; set; }
}
public class Solution
{
    [YamlMember(Alias = "results", ApplyNamingConventions = false)]
    public object Result { get; set; }
    public object Framework { get; set; }
}
public class Test
{
    public object Configuration { get; set; }
    [YamlMember(Alias = "results", ApplyNamingConventions = false)]
    public object Result { get; set; }
}

public class Deserializer
{
    private IDeserializer deserializer;

    public Deserializer()
    {
        this.deserializer = new DeserializerBuilder()
            .WithNamingConvention(CamelCaseNamingConvention.Instance)
            .Build();
    }

    public CalcYamlFile ParseYamlTagByType(string input)
    {
        return this.deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<object, object>>(input);
    }
}
    public static void GetTagsRecursive(ref List<Tuple<string, string>> addedTags, string keyName, object tagsSource)
    {
        if (addedTags == null)
        {
            addedTags = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        }

        if (tagsSource == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string rootName = keyName != null ? keyName + " " : "";

        if (tagsSource is Dictionary<object, object>)
        {
            foreach (var elem in (tagsSource as Dictionary<object, object>))
            {
                if (elem.Value is IEnumerable)
                {
                    GetTagsRecursive(ref addedTags, rootName + elem.Key.ToString(), elem.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(rootName + elem.Key.ToString(), elem.Value.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        else if (tagsSource is List<object>)
        {
            foreach (var elem in (tagsSource as List<object>))
            {
                if (elem is IEnumerable)
                {
                    GetTagsRecursive(ref addedTags, keyName, elem);
                }
                else
                {
                    addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(keyName, elem.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(keyName, tagsSource.ToString()));
        }
    }

  Gc >> clean >> location  >>  build/buildresults/
  Gc >> clean >> pattern  >>  *
  Gc >> clean >> location  >>  build/testresults/
  Gc >> clean >> pattern  >>  *
  Gc >> dependencies >> location  >>  blah
  Gc >> solution >> results  >>  build/buildresults/
  Gc >> test >> configuration  >>  Release
  Gc >> test >> results  >>  build/testresults/Release/windows/
```

now i need to create objects of my classes like the struture of this strings. Maybe its possible to achieve this already in the GetTagsRecursive function

Comment: If you design the YAML's structure yourself, why make two lists in the first place if they don't fit your desired class structure?

Comment: I dont designed the structer. But the code should deserialize in the class structure no matter what the structure looks like.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You do need a proper specification of the input structure, you cannot simply make *any* structure load into your classes.

Comment: I have tags that can be in the yaml file and all of them are in my custom class the only thing is can i ignore the list tag without removing it from the file or can i create after deserializing the list that i get four and not two

Comment: @flyx or how would you do that. Deserializing a yaml file and check if the tags that must occur are there. Maybe theres an easier way than deserialzing into custom classes

Comment: I am afraid I have only very basic knowledge of YamlDotNet. From what I can gather you would need to either implement `IYamlConvertible` or `INodeDeserializer` on `CalcYamlFile` to transform the structure, but the interface is very different from the YAML implementations I am familiar with so I am unsure how you can achieve what you want. Be aware that in YAML context, a *tag* is something like `!!str` or `!!map` and you seem to mean something different with the term so I advise to use a better term.