# Deserializing yamlFile with unknown structure to custom classes

Tags: c#, class, yaml, deserialization

I want to deserialize a yaml File with an unknown structure to my custom classes. I am not directly deserializing to the classes because I don't know the exact structure of the file and I need a list gc containing 4 objects with clean, dependencies, solution and test but I get 2 lists.

```
gc:
  - clean:
      - location: build/buildresults/
        pattern: '*'
      - location: build/testresults/
        pattern: '*'
    dependencies:
      location: blah
  - solution:
      results: build/buildresults/
    test:
      configuration: Release
      results: build/testresults/Release/windows/


    public static void GetTagsRecursive(ref List<Tuple<string, string>> addedTags, string keyName, object tagsSource)
    {
        if (addedTags == null)
        {
            addedTags = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
        }

        if (tagsSource == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string rootName = keyName != null ? keyName + ">>" : "";

        if (tagsSource is Dictionary<object, object>)
        {
            foreach (var elem in (tagsSource as Dictionary<object, object>))
            {
                if (elem.Value is IEnumerable)
                {
                    GetTagsRecursive(ref addedTags, rootName + elem.Key.ToString(), elem.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(rootName + elem.Key.ToString(), elem.Value.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        else if (tagsSource is List<object>)
        {
            foreach (var elem in (tagsSource as List<object>))
            {
                if (elem is IEnumerable)
                {
                    GetTagsRecursive(ref addedTags, keyName, elem);
                }
                else
                {
                    addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(keyName, elem.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            addedTags.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(keyName, tagsSource.ToString()));
        }
    }

    public class CalcYamlFile
    {
        [YamlMember(Alias = "gc", ApplyNamingConventions = false)]
        public CalcTag GcTag { get; set; }
    }

    public class CalcTag
    {
        public List<Clean> Clean { get; set; }
        public List<Dependencies> Dependencies { get; set; }
        public List<Solution> Solution { get; set; }
        public List<Test> Test { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clean
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Location is required")]
        public object Location { get; set; }
        public object Pattern { get; set; }
        public object Continue { get; set; }
    }
```

This returns a List<Tuple<string, string>> like that.

```
  Gc >> clean >> location  >>  build/buildresults/
  Gc >> clean >> pattern  >>  *
  Gc >> clean >> location  >>  build/testresults/
  Gc >> clean >> pattern  >>  *
  Gc >> dependencies >> location  >>  blah
  Gc >> solution >> results  >>  build/buildresults/
  Gc >> test >> configuration  >>  Release
  Gc >> test >> results  >>  build/testresults/Release/windows/
```

Can anyone help me deserialize a yaml file with an unknown structure to my custom classes?

Maybe you know an easier way or help me to create the objects in the `GetTagsRecursive` function or create the objects out of the `list<tuple>`.

In the end I need objects of `CalcyamlFile` containing clean, dependencies, solution and test.

Comment: Please don't create a new account to [ask the same question again](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67195700/347964). You can bump your original question by editing it with the additional code you show here.

Comment: Yeah other account not working properly but thanks for your information